# Attachment in PHP showing 0KB

Tags: php

I am trying to send files as attachment through php mail function. My code is sending the files but it is showing size 0KB. I already google it but didn't found a solution. Please help me.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="code.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename){
        $files[] = $filename; // create array of terms 
    }

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = "receiver_email_here";
    $from = "sender_email_here"; 
    $subject ="My subject"; 
    $message = "My message";
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


?>
```

I think I am doing something wrong in this part but I am not sure.

```
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open `$_FILES['file']['name']`, but the `name` field contains the name of the original file, not the path to the file on the server. To access the file on the server, use

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
```

Also to make sure that the file was uploaded correctly, use

```
$_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK
```